# Check whether directory exists "rel1.5" exists in Repository https://xx/svn/MobileApp/Tags if exists do some action else the other

Tags: svn, ant

Help me in doing this using Ant.

Ill pass label name ex: "rel1.5" in command line to ant script file, if the directory exists it should display "Choose other label name" else should perform svn copy i.e., tagging from branch.

Ex: 
Check whether directory exists "rel1.5" exists in Repository https://www.exampledomain.com/svn/MobileApp/Tags if exists do some action else the other..

Answer (score 0):

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

   <property name="tag" value="rel1.5"/>

   <condition property="url.exists">
      <http url=" https://www.exampledomain.com/svn/MobileApp/Tags/${tag}" errorsBeginAt="401"/>
   </condition>

   <target name="check1" if="url.exists">
      <echo message="URL exists"/>
   </target>

   <target name="check2" unless="url.exists">
      <echo message="URL does not exist"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build" depends="check1,check2">
   </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Whether URL exists or not i am getting the same output.check1:
Skipped because property 'url.exists' not set.

check2:
     [echo] URL does not exist

build:
     [echo] Check in

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: i am giving HTTPS request.

Comment: @user1421121 Sounds like the URL is not working as you expect over HTTPS. Use the "curl" command with the verbose option to see the HTTP return code. Note how my example specifies that errors begin at >= 401